# Objective-C loading while json request

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, mbprogresshud

I'm having a problem in doing a simple request while using `MBProgressHUD` to show a loading spinner.

It is a simple form with `username` and `password`, and when I press "Submit" I will have to make a `dataWithContentsOfURL:` request. Then I receive a json object in the response data and I have to work him out before I can `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

My current code is:

```
@try {
    if([user isEqualToString:@""] || [pass isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
    } else {
        NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl.com"];
        NSURL *jsonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
            });
        });
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonData); //gives error because jsonData is unknown....
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary *dic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR - %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }else
        {
            //doing stuff before perform segue
        }

    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"No connection to internet" :@""];
}
```

Outside those `disptch_async`, the code doesn't know what the `jsonData` object is, and when I declare it before the `dispatch_async` it gives me an error while trying to do the serialization:

> "ERROR - The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"

How can I show the spinner before the call and hide it after the call?

Answer (score 2):

@try @catch

Hmm not a good start - Are you a Java dev ?

It's my understanding that it's not very performant to do try catch in objective c.

But any way NSData* jsonData is declared inside your block hence why it's not available out side.

move

```
 NSLog(@"%@",jsonData); //gives error because jsonData is unknown....
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary *dic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR - %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }else
        {
            //doing stuff before perform segue
        }
```

inside the block and it'll work.

Comment: well i was using the try catch to check if connection available.. got that from random tutorial xD i will try to move everything inside the block

Comment: why does it take so much time to make the performwithsegue? after the spinner disappears, it takes about 10 or 15 seconds to do so... And also my UIAlertView doesn't pop out when errors are found

Comment: Those really are separate questions, but it depends on what you're sequing (your ViewController) to and what you're doing in the init and viewdidload methods and also viewwillappear. You are probably doing something that's slowing it down is the simple answer like maybe making network calls in the init or loading? It shouldn't take that long for a seque IMO.

Comment: An obvious question, is this code in your prepare for segue method ?. If it is move it and put some where else. As you should be making network calls as part of your seque. You should either run this first then transition to the next view or run it as part of the viewcontroller you're moving too.

Comment: thanks for the answer, no. I will choose which segue to use in relation to the response i get from the server...
                    if(evt.count>0)
                    {
                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"eventsel" sender:self];} else { //another segue}

Comment: Any chance you marking this as answered? Also it's worth bearing in mind that if you're waiting for a response from the server before you perform the segue that you may want to show some kind of activity indicator to the user, as it is this that is making the segue take a while.

Answer (score 2):

That block that you create with `dispatch_async` is separate from the rest of the method. That is to say that `jsonData`, which you create in that block, is invisible to the code that comes after the block. So move it into the block and you should be fine.

Your use of `try/catch` is somewhat strange to me, though. If you are coming from another language such as C# or Java where raising and catching exceptions is the norm, you might be tempted to do the same in Objective-C. However, Objective-C does things differently and exceptions are rarely used. Instead, you should use `NSError` instances where applicable and check your return values and such.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the spinner, it's your data handling. The download is synchronous on a background thread, but your code is treating it as synchronous on the current thread. You need to process the data inside the block after it's downloaded, and then pass the result back to the main thread to update your UI:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonData); //gives error because jsonData is unknown....

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR - %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        // doing stuff before perform segue - in the background => no UI updates
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // use the result here / trigger the segue and use the result in prepareForSegue:sender:

        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

The 2 errors you see currently are because:

1. Initially the variable isn't declared (it's in a different scope)
2. You try to deserialise a `nil` object (because the download hasn't completed yet)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it lifts me an error when I'm going to perform segue: due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

Comment: So you're not triggering the segue in the right place because it was still running on the background thread. It needs to be done inside dispatch_get_main_queue

Answer (score 0):

Why not move your JSON serialization code to another method and call it like this?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
    [self serializeJSONData:jsonData];
});

- (void) serializeJSONData:(NSData *)jsonData 
{
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *dic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR - %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else {
        //doing stuff before perform segue
    }
}
```

Comment: i was trying to implement your solution, but something happens when i do the perform segue inside serializeJSONData function... 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

Comment: and also the UIAlertView when something should pop up doesn't work also (invalid credentials, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I followed your advices but I had several problems:

- very slow performsegue's
- uialertview didn't show.

So after some research i changed my code a bit:

```
if([user isEqualToString:@""] || [pass isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
    } else {
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
```

The loading starts here and this queue goes all the way until the end.

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

   [self alertStatus:@"Credenciais Inválidas" :@"Aviso!"];
   });
```

Whenever I want to show an alert popup i just call the main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"admin" sender:self];
});
```

The same goes to whenever I want to performsegue....
Is this a good approach? So far I've had no problems